# PHP - User Agent mistery - I recieve IE6 but the web doesn't allow it

Tags: user-agent

I'm trying to find a bug, and to help me when this bug happens (in the server) I send an email to myself with some information.

I send the user agent that I obtain with: $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]

I have the bug normally with this agent:

"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"

is it Internet Explorer 6? is another origin possible?

But my web doesn't allow it, I've tried and I can't use it with IE6 I can't reproduce the error.

I have in the code:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script>alert('I\'m sorry, Note Board doesn\'t work in Internet Explorer 6.0 or 7.0');
document.location.href="index.php";</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Is it not correct? I've tried and It worked.

The web is http://noteboardapp.com/board.php?user=demo

Thank you!
Oscar.

Comment: You marked the question as php, but I don't see any php code here: only javascript.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you want to block IE6 or not? Relevant: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: User agent strings can be spoofed; just because a client claims to be IE6 doesn't mean it actually is IE6. It could be another browser using the IE6 UA string, or it could even be a bot scraping your site while pretending to be IE6.

Comment: I putted php because I obtain the agent with $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] and I don't know if the error is how obtein the agent or if the agent that I think is IE6 maybe come from another device.

Comment: Yes I want to block IE6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user agent string can be changed and often is.  There are many tools for changing this.  Someone is visiting your site with a browser that pretends to be IE6.

Since there are extensions for changing the user agent string in all of the major browsers, It could be any browser.  It could even be something that's not a browser.

As far as I know, only real Internet Explorer obeys conditional comments, but that could be faked too.

This is why it's not recommended to use the User agent string for anything.

Comment: And why would someone pretend to simulate that is using IE6? I would never confess ;) I don't want to allow IE6 because I use localStorage, I'll use modernizer. I'm sorry finally the post is not about PHP. Thank you